# One-way binding

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I know this question exists but I can't find the solution in the answers.

I have a form with a data-binding to a custom class so that when changing the form, the custom class gets notified (the inverse will never happen).

```
myForm.DataBindings.Add("Items", ItemsController.Singleton, "Items", false, 
                        DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

What is happening now is that when I create an instance of the form and set the Items property with some values, the data-binding checks for the ItemsController Items property and updates it back to the form with 0 Items, I want to prevent that using a one-way data-binding.

Is it possible or I will have to rely on event's only?

Comment: In DataBinding "OneWay" mean update direction only from DataSource to Form control.

Comment: From Form control to custom Class

Comment: Why you cannot set the items to the custom class `Items` property, then it is works. And remember to implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in your Custom class

Comment: Let me see. You want setting the form `Items` property to update the `ItemsController`, but not the opposite?

Comment: @Fabio that's one option, but since I used a Factory pattern to create the Form I wanted the factory to handle the binding between the two (thank you for trying to help, I just want to learn and I don't understand the downvotes :/)

Comment: @Ivan Stoev yes, that's it. As I explained in the previous comment I have one class responsible for creating the form (factory), the custom class is a Singleton. My idea was to do the binding in the factory so I have more flexibility. But because of the issue I described in the OP having a normal DataBinding is causing the factory to set the initial Form value, but then the binding fetches the custom class Items value and updates on the form loosing the correct value (as set by the factory). That is why I'm asking if there is any chance of defining a DataBinding oneway only..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you are seeking for [Binding.ControlUpdateMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Windows.Forms.Binding.ControlUpdateMode);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) property:

> Gets or sets when changes to the data source are propagated to the bound control property

```
myForm.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Items", ItemsController.Singleton, "Items")
{
    DataSourceUpdateMode = DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged,
    ControlUpdateMode = ControlUpdateMode.Never
});
```